# Time and Zones in Rails scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timezone

I have a scope like

```
scope :active_on_a_date, lambda { |date| where(:starts_at.gteq => date, :ends_at.lteq => date)}
```

Will the date passed will be converted to UTC by itself?? 
Or can anyone explain how date comparison occurs.
The date i am passing is Time.zone.now which is in IST +5.30 hrs

Answer (score 3):

Activerecord will convert from the local timezone to UTC and back for you.

An example from my production app.

I have this set in my application.rb

`config.time_zone = 'Wellington'`

(It is a good idea to be explicit about the app's timezone)

So in my case:

```
> Time.zone.now
 => Wed, 02 Nov 2011 21:12:58 NZDT +13:00
```

Rails console:

```
> Audio.find(661256).broadcast_at
 => Thu, 02 Nov 2006 21:06:00 NZDT +13:00
```

And in the database:

```
mysql> select broadcast_at from audio where audio.id = 661256;
+---------------------+
| broadcast_at        |
+---------------------+
| 2006-11-02 08:06:00 |
+---------------------+
```

The time in the DB is 13 hours behind the time in the Rails app. If I were to change my timezone to yours (IST) the times in Rails would be adjusted to suit, but the DB times stay the same.

Because the time returned and the time in your code are from the same zone, it is just a simple object comparison.